# Using Fabric Plugin in AndrStudio crashed my code

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

When using Fabric plugin inside Android Studio - it is inserting its instance into code

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

anyway looks like it will insert it in the middle of my current code - looks like at cursor position which can break user code

My example 
I had

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

after Fabric plugin execution I got

```
getActionBar().setHomeButFabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());tonEnabled(true);
```

one needs to correct it by hand

Comment: Hi Josef, Paul from Fabric here. Is this happening regularly, or just once?

Comment: for me it happend 2 times